# Add custom library in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a plain custom library that I want to add to my ember project. I need to use it across multiple controllers and routes, what is the standard way to do that? lib folder? as a helper? export as module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "plain" you mean the library is not written against ember, node, AMD, ES6 or anything else-- just plain JS.

Put your libarary into the `vendor` directory, then add this line in your `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
app.import('vendor/your-library.js');
```

Then you can access it globally.

Read more here: http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-non-amd-asset

Comment: export default {

    myFunction: function(message) {
    }
}

Comment: I wrap the code inside a module and put it on Libs folder. Is this a correct solution? Thanks.